# Not able to update the data using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following code. in that i am trying to update my data. but i am getting error message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="CompanyId,Address,EstbalishYear,Email,IsActive")] CompanyMaster companymaster)
    {
        if (companymaster.CompanyId == 0)
        {
            return View(companymaster);
        }
        CompanyMaster company = db.CompanyMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == companymaster.CompanyId);
        companymaster.Name = company.Name;
        companymaster.InsertedBy = company.InsertedBy;
        companymaster.InsertedTime = company.InsertedTime;
        companymaster.UpdatedBy = 1;
        companymaster.UpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;

        ModelState.Remove("Name");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(companymaster).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(companymaster);
    }
```

Please explain me how can I fix this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are working with **two** object instances of a company master, which in reality is a single entity, with the same ID.

One (*companyMaster*) comes as an argument to the Edit method, via binding.

The other one (*company*) you are selecting from the database through db.CompanyMasters by ID

What you can do is

1. Select company by ID, as you do now
2. Set company properties from companyMaster object (vice-versa, not like you do now)
3. Save the company object

Please find the sample code below.
Please also note that the best practice is not to use your persistence entity model in UI layer, but rather define a [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) with a minimum set of required fields, and then map it to your entity either manually or using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

```
    [HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="CompanyId,Address,EstbalishYear,Email,IsActive")] CompanyMaster companymaster)

    {
        if (companymaster.CompanyId == 0)
        {
            return View(companymaster);
        }
        CompanyMaster company = db.CompanyMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == companymaster.CompanyId);
        company.Address = companymaster.Address;
        company.EstbalishYear= companymaster.EstbalishYear;
        company.Email = companymaster.Email;
        company.IsActive= companymaster.IsActive;
        company.UpdatedBy = 1;
        company.UpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;

        ModelState.Remove("Name");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(companymaster);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. i got ur point but i have one query in mind. I want to get Name field value from the database. then how can i handle this?

Comment: @MohitModi, if you do not want to overwrite the Name, just do NOT set it.
Leave it as it was in DB, and do NOT set company.Name from companyMaster.Name

Comment: but if i not set CompanyName in Action Bind list. then it shows me error message 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'. I do not want user can change company name so i have not included that field in bind list. bcz any bady can change CompanyName by ajax call if i set that in Bind Parameter.

Comment: @MohitModi, you can leave it in the Action Bind list - just don't use it in your code - i.e. this line should not be present `company.Name= companyMaster.Name;`, and you could remove `ModelState.Remove("Name");` as well

Comment: but CompanyMaster.Name field have a required field validation on Model. then how can i handle this situation

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  now code is working as aspected. :-)